# Getting message "The type org.aopalliance.aop.Advice cannot be resolved." in spring java program

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, aop

I'm trying to set up the spring AOP example from this page:

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/51-introduction-to-springs-aspect-oriented-programminga-4.html

I'm using Eclipse Indigo as my development environment.

On these lines:

```
public class LogAfterThrowsAdvice implements ThrowsAdvice{

public class LogAfterReturningAdvice implements AfterReturningAdvice{ 

public class LogBeforeCallAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
```

I'm getting the message:

> The type org.aopalliance.aop.Advice cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files

I downloaded the org.aopalliance package from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/

The jar file is aopalliance-alpha1.jar. It does not contain the path org.aopalliance.aop. I'm wondering if I should be using a different aopalliance jar file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I downloaded the jar from here:

http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.aopalliance&version=1.0.0

and that fixed my issues.