# i am getting bean creation exception when i am try to use aspects in bean class

Tags: spring, spring-aop

when i am try to work with AOP IN application am getting following error can any one help to resolve this issue.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at TestAop.main(TestAop.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1004)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.<init>(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.GlobalAdvisorAdapterRegistry.<clinit>(GlobalAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:32)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:115)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:47)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.<init>(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a very similar problem to this question:

[Getting message "The type org.aopalliance.aop.Advice cannot be resolved." in spring java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214875/getting-message-the-type-org-aopalliance-aop-advice-cannot-be-resolved-in-spr)

Missing AOP Alliance dependency JAR.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same problem resolved by adding jar
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0